# Do I need to have the asp.net mvc framework to run my asp.net mvc apps on a web server?

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting, web-applications, asp.net-mvc

I have been looking for a web hosting service for a while and I would like to know if I need the asp.net framework besides the .net framework to run my asp.net mvc applications? And I also want to ask for recomended web hosting that provides the .net framework, php (doesn't matter what version), 5 GB or more of space, below 15 CAN dollars and 100 GB or more of bandwidth.

Comment: Our esteemed host did many blog entries about building the servers for these sites ... the info about asp.net mvc might be there. blog.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I think that you will get a better response in stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ok stackoverflow was my second stop on my list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article "[How to: Deploy an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407.aspx)" has the answer to your first question.

asp.net is needed.

I don't know about recommended hosting providers.